# sublimetext3 - broken js syntax in php file

Tags: javascript, php, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Sublime Text - Version 3.0, Build 3143

I deal with a lot of php files that contain HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The only problem I've found so far is when I'm looking at script tags in a PHP file. The syntax is set to PHP but comments outside of JS functions break the rest of the code below it (it looks like it's trying to detect regex?)

[image: broken syntax]

When I move the `// test` comment into the function then all is well:

[image: proper syntax]

I'm curious to know where the problem exists and maybe find a fix.

- Color Scheme doesn't affect the syntax highlighting (it still breaks in other color schemes)
- Adding `type="text/javascript"` to the script tag doesn't fix anything

My finger points to the PHP syntax highlighting ... but if that's the case, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh install of Build 3143(Windows), opened as "PHP" and everything works. It can be caused by some custom settings you made or third party plugin.

[image]

Comment: Time to start removing packages! :P

Comment: It's been a while but... a third party package was the issue.